# Get Sum of a Laravel Datatable column using Yajra Datatable

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

I want to have the summation of a column and want to show on the datable footer. I tried to pass the summation of the attribute from the Controller, but it is giving a 500 Error. Please, anyone, share me the code for taking out a sum of an attribute and show in the Datatable Footer.

```
return datatables()->of($query)->make('false')
                ->with('total_amount', $query->sum('amount'));
```

Comment: What is the description of the 500 error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code block may help you:

```
->with('total', function() use ($query) {
     return $query->sum('amount');
})
```

Comment: Iam using ajax paging. How to showing SUM of current page only, not all of pages?